# How to use a TableView inside a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uistoryboard

I want to add a simple static TableView to my UIView. So i dragged it into my UIView. Added the TableViewDataSource and Delegate Protocols to my ViewController class. Created an outlet to my tableview and connected the datasource and delegate outlets to the viewcontroller.
But i still get an error message which says that Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewCOntroller Instances ? Any Ideas how to solve this Problem ?
PS: I am using UIStoryboards for designing the UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a containerView (drag one onto your UIView) which will link to a UITableViewController instead.  You will use the prepareForSegue method to initialize the table view controller.
Oh, and you might want to accept answers that help you or no one will help you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want static cells, in your Storyboard, click on the tableview, then in the inspector, change the `Content` from 'Dynamic Prototypes' to `Static Cells`. You can also segue these cells to a new controller without having to set up data sources and delegates for the table.